# How to log to a specific file?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have a `log4j2` logger configuration that basically write all logging of the root logger to a basic logging file. I always use `Logger.getRootLogger` here.

For some specific events I'd like to log do a different file. How could I configure such a logger in the properties file (eg give it a name that I can then reference from code)?

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html Did you try?  You only need to define rot level O_o for each file.

Comment: Down-vote from me - really not clear what you researched before asking this question. It strikes me as being basic functionality that I would imagine the manuals cover in detail?

Comment: I don't want to log ALL logs of a specific level into a certain file. Please read carefully. I want to log SOME statements of the same level to a specific file, while others of the SAME level should go to global file using rootlogger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that `Marker`s are the way to route messages:

[What is markers in Java Logging frameworks and that is a reason to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813032/what-is-markers-in-java-logging-frameworks-and-that-is-a-reason-to-use-them)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
    log4j.appender.transaction=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.transaction.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
    log4j.appender.transaction.File=logs/transaction.log
    log4j.appender.transaction.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.transaction.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p %c{2}\:%L - %m%n
    log4j.appender.transaction.threshold=info

    log4j.logger.transaction=INFO, transaction
```

Comment: And how is this to be used in code? I don't want all `INFO` events to be logged with this logger. Only specific info events. How do I call this logger?

Comment: `Logger transactionLog = Logger.getLogger("transaction");` I guess.

Comment: Actually in log4j2 it is `LogManager.getLogger("transaction")`. More details here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html