# slf4j/log4j logging using markers

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

First, I have found a SO question that seems very relevant:

[How can I set up separate streams of logging for log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292766/how-can-i-set-up-separate-streams-of-logging-for-log4j/30552012#30552012)

The first answer to the question discusses using Markers and this is what I'd like to try to use. However, I have not been able to get the logging to actually work as expected. I don't know if I'm missing a step or using the wrong syntax.

I wrote a really simple program in an attempt to test this out.

```
package my.package;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;

public class LoggingTest {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingTest.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Marker marker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("MARKER");
    logger.info(marker, "log info to marker log");
    logger.info("log info to regular log");
  }

}
```

log4j.xml:

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
  <!-- APPENDERS -->
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5p: %c{2}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="session.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5p: %c{2}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="marker-file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="marker.log" />
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <MarkerFilter marker="MARKER" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5p: %c{2}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!-- LOGGERS -->
  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="marker-file" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The logging right now is just set to log to the marker appender. I would need to figure out how to set up the logger(s) to send "marker" output to the marker appender and the rest to the "regular" appender.

I don't know if the syntax of the usage of the `MarkerFilter` element is correct or not.

When I execute the program, I am specifying the VM argument `-Dlog4j.configuration=file://<path to log4j.xml>`.

I'm running this from within eclipse and I'm having a separate problem where it doesn't seem to be recognizing the log4j.xml file I'm giving it. I assume this is something I'm doing wrong (and is probably the reason why what I'm trying to do does not appear to work).

Any ideas as to what I might be doing incorrectly as far as getting the log4j.xml to be recognized, and then if that all checks out, whether I'm using the filter/marker mechanism correctly or not, would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I am doing this on a Windows box, so I suspect something is amiss with how I'm specifying the file URI to the log4j.xml file.

Comment: I think I might have found reasons behind the issues I'm having. I am using log4j 1.2.x and I just realized that markers are a feature of log4j 2.