# Logback add custom field/fields in all the logs

Tags: java, logging, logback, spring-logback

For a Spring application I want to add a custom field to the log.
Currently I use the default format but I want to add a custom field (category field) which should be present in all the logs:

```
W:Action D:2022-01-10 23:21:03.285 L:INFO C:c.h.l.LoggingDemoApplication F:StartupInfoLogger.java(61) Fn:logStarted T:main R: - Hello World
```

What are the best solution to add a custom field to the logback log?

What I studied until now are the following possible solutions:

1. Use marker. The disadvantage with this is that it's not scalable: if in future you need another custom field can't add another marker. Further based on some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165558/best-practices-for-using-markers-in-slf4j-logback) the marker is best suited to mark special logs that need to be handle differently.
2. Use MDC.

   Also using this it seems not the best solution because:

   - It keeps the context so if there are multiple log statements in the same function, before each `logger.info()` there should be `MDC.put("category", "action")`
   - The code becomes to verbose.
3. Create a custom convertor ([link](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier)). Get the arguments from the ILoggingEvent, get argument of 0. If this is the same type as category enum, then use it. The call for this is like `logger.info("Message here: {} {} {}", CatEnum.Action.getValue(), msg1, msg2, msg3)`.
4. Create some static method in which the final format is generated.
   Pattern is similar to: `<pattern>%m%n</pattern>`

   To log, something like this should be used: `logger.info(customFormatter.fmtLog(CatEnum.Action.getValue(), msg))`. The returned value of fmtLog should be all the info from default logging  + the category field.

Are there any built in solutions to add a custom field?

Comment: MDC is static, I believe, so no, there doesn't need to be a put call before every log statement, only when you actually need to change the category, Your other solution is to imlpement your own logger methods/class

Comment: Yes, I agree to what you said regarding the put call.